# Detectar cámaras en red por AForge y poder hacer uso de ellas

Tags: c#, qr, zxing, aforge

tengo un desarrollo en donde requiero obtener el QR que escanea una cámara de hikvision.

Tengo una aplicación de escritorio en C# la cual trabaja con el SDK de Hikvision y me ayuda a hacer el stream en mi aplicación.
La tarea es que usando esta cámara debo detectar el QR que presente el usuario, hacer mi validación y mandar a abrir el torniquete.

Usando la tecnología de AForge logro que la aplicación detecte las cámaras de la computadora, pero no encuentro la forma de conectarme y aplicar la tecnología de zxing a la imagen del stream ya que esta conexión es por red.

Si alguien tiene una idea, le agradecería mucho.

En este código cargo las cámaras del equipo, lo que quiero es detectar una cámara por IP.

```
private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            filter = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

            foreach (FilterInfo filterInfo in filter)
                comboBox1.Items.Add(filterInfo.Name);
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;


        }
```